# Compact Subsets of $C[a,b]$

Tags: analysis, compactness

Consider the set $G = \lbrace f \in C\left[a,b\right] : |f(x)| \le |g(x)|,\ \forall x \in [a,b] \rbrace$

Find all values of $g$'s for which $G$ is a compact subset of $C[a,b]$ with the max norm.

Attempts:

I understand the fact that it suffices to just show that the set $G$ is closed because we know that $C[a,b]$ with the infinity norm is in fact a compact subspace.  However, for which value of $g$ will these sets be dense?  My first intuition on the argument would be that the only necessary conditions on $g$ would be that it ins in $C[a,b]$ and that any function would do.

However, my only real justification is that given any function $f \in G$ we know that if $O$ is any neighborhood of $f$ $\exists p(x) \in G$ such that $p(x) \in O$ by the density of polynomials in $C[a,b]$.  However, first hand I don't know whether or not this is necessarily true, I also have no intuition on showing such a function exists.

Any ideas? Or is showing that $G$ is closed not the right choice for the proof.

Edit: Problem in inequality
Edit2: Now knowing that $C[a,b]$ is not compact.

Comment: If you have $<$ and not $\leq$ there, then $G$ is compact only when it's empty, because it's open (and there're no proper clopen sets there). Or do I miss something?

Comment: $C[a,b]$ with the supremum norm is **not** a compact space, so showing closedness won't suffice.  In fact, there are **extremely** few $g$ with this property.  You might consider this: a set is not compact iff it contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence.  Then observe that it suffices to find a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a discontinuous function, for then no subsequence can converge uniformly to a continuous function.

Comment: Also, in your question, it looks like "compact" and "dense" are mixed up in a few places?

Comment: Edit: Yes you were right.  The < should be <=

Comment: Also, $g$ is not required to be continuous, right?

Comment: Nope, g has to be continuous as well. Sorry for all the problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is the answer after the question has been edited.

We claim that $g\equiv 0$. If not, there exists $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)\neq 0$. $g$ is continuous, so there exists $\varepsilon>0$ so that $|g(x)|>\varepsilon$ close to $x_0$. So, $|g(x)|>\varepsilon$ in an interval of the form $(c,d)$. Let $k$ be the middle point of $(c,d)$, and consider the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}0,& x\leq k-\frac{1}{n}\,\,\text{or}\,\,x\geq k+\frac{1}{n}\\ \frac{n\varepsilon}{2}(x-k)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},&k-\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq k \\ -\frac{n\varepsilon}{2}(x-k)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},&k\leq x\leq k+\frac{1}{n}\end{array}\right.$$ Those functions belong to $G$, and $G$ is compact, so $(f_n)$ should have a convergent subsequence. But $f_n$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, which gives a contradiction.

So, $g\equiv 0$.